# Deserialization malformed JSON with custom constructor

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Is there any way to deserialize this malformed JSON code?

```
{
"children": [
{
  "bold": false,
  "italic": false,
  "strike": false,
  "underline": false,
  "link": false
},
"Hello world" ]
}
```

JsonSerializerOptions has the option of a custom Converters.

Would anyone know how to show me the way?

Thank you.

Comment: if it has '{' and '}' then it is no malformed

Comment: It is a valid json if you add {}. What do you want as an output?

Comment: I have updated the code. The file is an array with only one element, the other is a string. The deserializer fails. Is there an option I don't know about?

Comment: What data do you need? There are many ways to get data from json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simpliest way to deserialize your json is

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

public class Data
{
    public List<object> children { get; set; }
}
```

how to use

```
string helloWorld=data.children[1].ToString();

Dictionary<string,bool> fonts= ((JObject) data.children[0]).ToObject<Dictionary<string,bool>>();
```